# how to pass tableview index path row value in another controller in swift?

Tags: ios

in my app i used tab bar  controller and in those view controller used tableview. when i click on one table row value and it  value can access in another  view controller. i have try using segue but it can give error "can not used segue it used only in navigation controller" what i do ??? Thanks

Here is my code.

```
 var row = ""
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    row = itemid[indexPath.row]

    var db1 = NewVehicalViewController()
    db1.temp = row

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("updatevehicalsegue", sender: tableView)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "updatevehicalsegue"){
        var vrc = segue.destinationViewController as NewVehicalViewController;

     vrc.temp = row           
    }
}
```

Comment: Your UITableViewController must be embed inside a UINavigationController to perform segue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UITableViewController` needs to be embed-ed in a `UINavigationController`.

To do this, select your tableViewController object in storyboard, go to `Editor` on top, select `Embed In` and select `Navigation Controller`.